# How to use Optional.map()

Tags: java, java-8

Consider the below interfaces:

```
public interface Vc{
}

public interface Vd< P extends Vc, C extends Vcc<{
...
}

public interface VcResult extends Vc{
}
```

There exists a method which returns Optional

```
public Optional<Vc> getData()
```

Here is the method where I am trying to improve the code:

```
public VcResult mainMethod(){
  Optional<Vc> vc = getData();
  if(vc.isEmpty){
    return anotherMethod();  
  }
  return (VcResult)vc.get();
}
```

Please suggest in converting this portion:

```
if(vc.isEmpty){
      return anotherMethod();  
   }
   return (VcResult)vc.get();
```

to this:

```
vc.map()..orElseGet(() -> anotherMethod());
```

What will be the argument of map in the above statement.

Comment: No need for `.map()`, directly do `.orElseGet()` on the optional - `vc.orElseGet(() -> anotherMethod());` and cast if necessary the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `VcResult`'s class object to cast it:

```java
public VcResult mainMethod(){
    return getData().map(VcResult.class::cast).orElseGet(this::anotherMethod);
}
```

Comment: I wonder if `map(vc -> (VcResult) vc)` would be more *appropriate*... or just `return (VcResult) getData().orElseGet(this::anotherMethod);` (OK, get question was about using `map()`)

Comment: @user85421 there’s no relevant difference between `map(VcResult.class::cast)` or `map(vc -> (VcResult)vc)` The actual question should be whether it is really guaranteed that `getData()` always returns an encapsulated `VcResult` and if so, why does declare `Optional<Vc>` as return type instead of `Optional<VcResult>`. And why did the OP bother us with the entirely unrelated `Vd` type…